# Java Date and utcTimeOffset

Tags: java, timezone, datetime-conversion, date

I have a Java Date (`java.util.Date`) - Tue Jul 31 00:53:43 CEST 2018 and a utcTimeOffset = +0200, which says that give, date is +2 hours from UTC.

This is a legacy code and Java 8 is not an option. What I am getting is text representation of date as `20180730131847` and utcTimeOffset = `+0200` from a third-party API.

I would like to convert this to Danish time. Can someone help me how to do this please.

Comment: I recommend searching this site (and others) first, and making an attempt.

Comment: Use `ZonedDateTime` from Java 8. It makes everything easier.

Comment: CEST, Central European is one hour offset, plus day time saving = 2 h.

Comment: If you have a Java `Date`, you don't actually have a time zone. That's just how it prints in your local system. A Java `Date` signifies milliseconds since January 1st, 1970 at midnight UTC. In any case it's recommended not to work with `Date` but with the `java.time` classes, and reading up about how to represent or print time zone information.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  This is a legacy code and Java 8 is not an option. What i am getting is text representation of date as 20180730131847 and utcTimeOffset = +0200 from a third-party  api.

Comment: Denmark (my country) follows Central European Time and also Central European Summer Time (CEST) in summer, and @JoopEggen is correct, this is at offset +0200. So in some sense you have already got what you are asking for.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. is correct that `ZonedDateTime` is the good and correct class to use. You don’t need Java 8. java.time, the modern Java date and time API that includes `ZonedDateTime`, has been backported to Java 6 and 7 in [the ThreeTen Backport library](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Follow the link, add the library to your project and start coding.

Comment: @SarangaJayatilake Thanks for your additional information in response to the comments. It’s always best to add supplementary information in the question itself to keep all information in one place. This time I added it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### java.time, the modern Java date and time API

```
    ZoneId danishTime = ZoneId.of("Europe/Copenhagen");
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss");
    DateTimeFormatter offsetFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("XX");

    String dateTimeString = "20180730131847";
    String offsetString = "+0200";
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.from(offsetFormatter.parse(offsetString));
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, dateTimeFormatter)
            .atOffset(offset)
            .atZoneSameInstant(danishTime);
    System.out.println("Danish time: " + dateTime);
```

Output from this code is:

> Danish time: 2018-07-30T13:18:47+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]

The time zone to use for Denmark is Europe/Copenhagen. While the Faroe islands and Greenland use other time zones and are in a national community (“rigsfællesskab”) with Denmark under the same queen, they are not part of Denmark proper, so can be ignored when Danish time is asked for. Since Danish summer time agrees with your example offset of +0200, in this case we get the same time out as we put in. With a date in winter, for example, this would not have been the case because Danish standard time is at offset +0100.

### Java 8 is not an option

No big problem. java.time has been backported.

- In Java 8 and later and on new Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310, where the modern API was first described). Link below.
- On (older) Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. Make sure you import the date and time classes from package `org.threeten.bp` and subpackages.

In the backport the classes are in package `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages, for example `org.threeten.bp.ZoneId` and `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Comment: V.V, Thank you for restructuring my update. Appreciate for the comments from everybody.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Your input is in a poor format, but in this case can be parsed using the modern *java.time* classes. Note that unfortunate use of 3-4 letter pseudo-zone such as `CEST` are not standardized and are not unique so they cannot always be parsed as your intended zone.

For Java 8 and later, these classes are built-in. For Java 6 & 7, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* project detailed below.

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(    // Parse an input string as a date-time moment.
    "Tue Jul 31 00:53:43 CEST 2018" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu", Locale.US )                 // Specify `Locale` to determine human language and cultural norms to be used in translation.
)                       // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.withZoneSameInstant(   // Adjust from one zone to another.
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Copenhagen" )  // Always use `Continent/Region` time zone names, never 3-4 letter pseudo-codes such as `CEST`.
)
.toString()             // Generate a `String` with text in standard ISO 8601 format wisely extended by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

> 2018-07-31T00:53:43+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]

## java.time

This has been covered many times already, so search Stack Overflow for more discussion.

### Parse

```
String input = "Tue Jul 31 00:53:43 CEST 2018";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu", Locale.US );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f  );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-07-31T00:53:43+02:00[Europe/Paris]

### Adjust

Adjust to a Denmark time zone. I will arbitrarily choose the `Europe/Copenhagen`. [Denmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denmark) may have other zones, such as for Greenland or other parts of the kingdom.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Copenhagen" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtCopenhagen = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( z );  // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

> 2018-07-31T00:53:43+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]

Notice that on that date and hour, Paris and Copenhagen [time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) shared the same [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), so they perceive the same time-of-day.

## ISO 8601

Your input string is using a *terrible* format. It is difficult to parse, assumes English language, and includes redundant information.

When exchanging date-time values as text, use only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

Note that the `ZonedDateTime` class wisely extends that format to append the name of the time zone in square brackets. This is seen in output above.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).